# How are fuel leaks discovered on a rocket?

Tags: launch, rockets, fuel, construction

Most are aware of the fact that the [launch of GSLV](http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/isro-calls-off-gslv-launch-after-fuel-leak/article5038402.ece) has been aborted due to a fuel leakage, but how was the cryogenic fuel leak discovered? I'm not interested in this case only, but in general.

What techniques are employed to find fuel leakages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Pressure Drops. Generally there are multiple sensors which means you
  can localise the area.
- Thermal Camera. Rocket Fuel is generally kept
  cold. So any leaks are going to show up.
- Unexplained Gas Emissions.
  It is quite easy to see venting of something from where it should not
  be.

Comment: How to discover the location of a leak in a large hydrogen tank using several pressure sensors? The size of the leak is unknown.

Comment: You don't need to know *where* the leak is, to decide to abort the launch.  Knowing of the leak's existence is sufficient reason.